# Restore a _remote_ file after solving a merge conflict using

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash

I've done several changes on my local files in a parallel branch. I used `git stash` to save my changes and to get other changes into master without having to push online. So I had to solve some merge conflicts about files redundant files. Step by step, this is my code on git bash:

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
git mergetool
```

I solved conflict about one file `myFile.py` using meld as `mergetool`. My problem is that I forgot a huge part of code in the remote file (`myFile_remote_7572.py`) during the merge step. Right now, I'm not able to find the file anywhere on my laptop. I want to restore it in order to find my last code without restarting merge step. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming "have forgotten a huge part of code in the remote file" means that you discarded stuff that the remote part would bring in and overwrote it with your own changes.

The content is still present in your repository.

If you haven't done any further commits, you can recover the merge conflicts in a particular file with this command:

```
git checkout --merge -- that/particular/file
```

Of course, this also brings back the conflicts in that file that you have already resolved. There is no way to keep those and still recover the unresolved part. (All of this does *not* affect conflicts -- resolved or not -- in *other* files.)

If all fails, you still have the stash available, and you can start over again with all merge conflicts in all files:

```
git reset --hard   # warning! erases all your uncommitted changes
git stash apply    # recover the stash and all its conflicts
```

Despite you said `git stash pop` that stash was not lost because Git doesn't actually "pop" it when there are merge conflicts. This gives you another opportunity to say `git stash apply`.

If I were in your position, I would do the following (which is slightly expert usage):

```
git commit -a           # keep a record of what I have done so far
git reset --hard HEAD~  # go back before the commit to start over
git stash apply
git checkout --merge -- that/particular/file
git rerere forget -- that/particular/file
```

You may notice that Git remembers merge resolutions that were committed on the local computer to help when a merge is repeated. This is a bit awkward here, because it remembers *and re-uses* the wrong resolution in `that/particular/file`. Therefore, I ask Git to forget the resolution using `git rerere forget`.

Comment: Git will only remember the committed resolution if you have enabled `rerere`, which is not the default.